# display only ngTrueValue and ngFalseValue to numbers

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array

I am following an angular tutorial and i am introducing myself the ngTrueValue/ngFalseValue angular directives from check-boxes.

html code like:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
     {{c.value}}
     <input type="text" value="{{c}}"/>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="c.checkbox1" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="checkbox == 1" />
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="c.checkbox2" ng-true-value="2" ng-false-value="1" ng-checked="checkbox == 1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Script code like:

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.checkbox = 1;

    $scope.$watch(function(){
        return $scope.checkbox;
    }, function(){
        $scope.checkbox = Number($scope.checkbox);
        console.log($scope.checkbox, typeof $scope.checkbox);
    },true);
}
```

on run time code out put display :

> {"checkbox1":"1","checkbox2":"1"}

not display  text display only like this:

> {"1","2"}

Comment: As you are using `{{c}}`, it shows complete object.

Comment: yes , i am new in angularjs if any then tell me

Comment: The text you're expecting (`{"1","2"}`) is not even valid JSON. Why would you expect such invalid JSON to be displayed. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i just take a value of the checkbox if any idea then share me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write like this:

`{{c.checkbox1 + "," + c.checkbox2}}`

You can do this when you have many values:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in c track by $index">
    {{c.checkbox+$index}}
</div>
```

Comment: thank you sai this right answers but it work only static but the dynamic value is come more than that time how to use ?

Comment: thank you sai but i get slow that problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41219128/7255740

Comment: Sorry, not understood what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app='test' ng-controller="Test">
 <div ng-repeat="album in albums">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="album.selected" value={{album.name}} /> {{album.name + ","}}
    </div>
  
  
  <button type='button' ng-click="save1()">Save</button><br>
  Saved results:<br>
  {{albumNameArray}}<br>
{{''+ albumNameArray + ''}}
  <script>
  angular.module('test', [])

.controller('Test', function($scope){
  $scope.albums = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'test3'
  }];
  
  $scope.save1 = function(){
    $scope.albumNameArray = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.albums, function(album){
      if (album.selected) $scope.albumNameArray.push(album.name);
    });
  }
})
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```